# Sort files/objects with numbers and letters (alphanumeric) names

Tags: r, sorting, alphanumeric

My files are:

```
CT.BP.50.txt
CT.BP.200.txt
CT.BP.500.txt 
GP.BP.50.txt
GP.BP.200.txt 
GP.BP.500.txt 

files <- c("CT.BP.50.txt", "CT.BP.200.txt", "CT.BP.500.txt", "GP.BP.50.txt", "GP.BP.200.txt", "GP.BP.500.txt")
```

I want to perform specific operation on them, I can do this:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    foo <- read.table(files[i])
    barplot(table(foo$V1), main = files[i])
}
```

But R plots them in this order:

> "CT.BP.200.txt"   "CT.BP.500.txt" "CT.BP.50.txt"   "GP.BP.200.txt" "GP.BP.500.txt" "GP.BP.50.txt"

And I want them to be plotted in sorted order:

> "CT.BP.50.txt" "CT.BP.200.txt"   "CT.BP.500.txt"
>   "GP.BP.50.txt" "GP.BP.200.txt" "GP.BP.500.txt"

How sort objects with alphanumeric names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `list.files()` returns the file names in standard (lexically) sorted order, and the digits are being compared position by position rather than as part of a number.

```
files <- sort(c("Gen.Var_CT.BP.200.txt", "Gen.Var_CT.BP.500.txt", 
                "Gen.Var_CT.BP.50.txt", "Gen.Var_GP.BP.200.txt",
                "Gen.Var_GP.BP.500.txt", "Gen.Var_GP.BP.50.txt"))
```

On my system, this gives:

```
> files
[1] "Gen.Var_CT.BP.200.txt" "Gen.Var_CT.BP.50.txt"  "Gen.Var_CT.BP.500.txt"
[4] "Gen.Var_GP.BP.200.txt" "Gen.Var_GP.BP.50.txt"  "Gen.Var_GP.BP.500.txt"
```

The function `gtools::mixedsort` will (in general) sort the way you want: series of digits in a string will be treated as numbers for sorting purposes.  There is a bit of a snag with your example, though, because `mixedsort` assumes `.` are part of numbers and so sees `.200.` as a potential number, which can't actually be sorted as a number.  Since your examples don't have actual decimal points within them, you can get around this.

```
files <- files[mixedorder(gsub("\\.", " ", files))]
```

So files is now sorted as:

```
> files
[1] "Gen.Var_CT.BP.50.txt"  "Gen.Var_CT.BP.200.txt" "Gen.Var_CT.BP.500.txt"
[4] "Gen.Var_GP.BP.50.txt"  "Gen.Var_GP.BP.200.txt" "Gen.Var_GP.BP.500.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

Might this do it?

```
files <- c("Gen.Var_CT.BP.50.txt", "Gen.Var_CT.BP.200.txt", "Gen.Var_CT.BP.500.txt",    "Gen.Var_GP.BP.50.txt", "Gen.Var_GP.BP.200.txt", "Gen.Var_GP.BP.500.txt"){
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  b <- read.table(files[i])
  barplot(table(b$V1), main=files[i])
```

Comment: How should I automatically "c" files when there are much more of them (>100)

Comment: Oh. It sounded like you just had 6 files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to sort by particular components of your filename in a particular order.

So I would start by breaking the filename into its components with something like:

```
filesmat=matrix(unlist(strsplit(files,split='\\.')),byrow=T,ncol=4)
```

then extract columns that you want to sort by.

```
numbercomponent=as.numeric(filesmat[,3])

varname=filesmat[,1]
```

Then reorder the filenames with something like

```
files=files[order(varname,numbercomponent)]
```

Then just plot anyway you want.